# new language not work in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.1

i use magento ver 2.1.1 and create persian language . but some word not translate to persian In the event that the word translated !

**my language is fa_IR .**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the language module resource link.

Comment: https://up.uploadfiles.io/file/fd43030